# how to access attributes of linked entity?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I fetch all `Item` with their linked `Location`, and want to show the name of each item together with the name of its location:

```
var query = new QueryExpression("xxxxx_item");
query.ColumnSet.AddColumns("xxxxx_name");
var locationLink = query.AddLink("xxxxx_location", "xxxxx_location", "xxxxx_locationid", JoinOperator.LeftOuter)
locationLink.ColumnSet.AddColumns("xxxxx_name");

var result = crmService.RetrieveMultiple(query).Entities.Select(e => e.ToEntity<xxxx_Item>()).ToList();
```

How do I loop over the resulting List and show both `Item.Name` and the `Item.Location.Name` ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of Aliased Values in c# w.r.t Entity Framework.

Here are refrenced linked which will help you solve the issue

1. [Obtain value of an Aliased Value from a Linked Entity](https://mscrmdeveloper.wordpress.com/2014/10/27/obtain-value-of-an-aliased-value-from-a-linked-entity/)
2. [Easy use of AliasedValue in Dynamics CRM plugins](https://www.thrives.be/dynamics-365-ce/aliasedvalue-dynamics-crm-plugins/)
3. [Get AliasedValue attributes with Early Bound](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/nunoscrmblog/posts/get-aliasedvalue-attributes-with-early-bound)
4. [AliasedValue Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.sdk.aliasedvalue?view=dynamics-general-ce-9)

Comment: So, there is no way to use standard objects with their values? there is no "official" way instead of using something like helperclasses, as Nathan explained on https://www.thrives.be/dynamics-365-ce/aliasedvalue-dynamics-crm-plugins/ ?

Comment: Not other than aliased value as far as I know

Answer (score 1):

You should do this

```
var query = new QueryExpression("xxxxx_item");
query.ColumnSet.AddColumns("xxxxx_name");
var locationLink = query.AddLink("xxxxx_location", "xxxxx_location", 
"xxxxx_locationid", JoinOperator.LeftOuter)
locationLink.ColumnSet.AddColumns("xxxxx_name");
locationLink.EntityAlias = "Location";
query.LinkEntities.Add(locationLink);
var result = orgService.RetrieveMultiple(query);
foreach(var entity in result.Entities)
        {
              if (entity.Contains("Location.xxxxx_name"))
            {
                AliasedValue value = (AliasedValue)entity["Location.xxxxx_name"];
                EntityReference entityref = (EntityReference)value.Value;
            }
        }
```